# about the shadow of mask layer

Tags: ios, mask, shadow

when i set the cell imageView shadow like this:

```
[[[self imageView] layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[[[self imageView] layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 2)];
[[[self imageView] layer] setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[[[self imageView] layer] setShadowRadius:MASK_LAYER_RADIUS];


self.maskLayer = [[[CALayer alloc] init] autorelease];
[_maskLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIImage imageNamed:name].size.width, [UIImage imageNamed:name].size.height)];
[_maskLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
[_maskLayer setCornerRadius:MASK_LAYER_RADIUS];
[_maskLayer setOpacity:MASK_LAYER_OPACITY];
[_maskLayer setShadowColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
[_maskLayer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 2)];
[_maskLayer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[_maskLayer setShadowRadius:MASK_LAYER_RADIUS];
[self.imageView.layer setMask:_maskLayer];
```

i'm sorry  i can't upload the image of effect

when i runing  i find  the  ShadowRadius have no effect? i can see the corner

thanks.

Comment: The shadowRadius (both of the imageView layer and the mask layer) is working as designed.  The alpha channel of the mask defines the alpha channel of the layer it is attached to.  This means you'll never see colors like gray and green for the mask.  If you're trying to put a smooth fade out at the edges of the image, putting a shadow on the mask layer may work.  If you want to see a green shadow, it will need to be on a visible layer, not on a mask.

Answer (score 6):

It's because your mask and shadow are on the same layer, so you mask your shadow as well.

I've written a blog post with code going over a simple technique to mask and shadow an image in iOS: http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/08/ios-how-to-mask-and-shadow-an-image/